# How to not show warnings in Create React App

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I'm using create-react-app from Facebook, when it starts via 'npm start' it shows me a list of warnings, such as:

'Bla' is defined but never used
Expected '===' and instead saw '=='

I don't want to see any of these warnings, is there a way to supress them?

Comment: Why would you want to disable those warnings? It isn't hard to fix them and they won't be there in production

Comment: If you insist on ignoring them, the terminal prints a hint on how to do it when you run the start script

Comment: The hint it for single files, not for all files

Comment: You can eject and remove eslint from the project

Comment: You can always remove the entire eslint if you want 0 warnings. If you want a specific rule to stop warning you, edit you .eslintrc file

Comment: @Craig1123 I'm not OP, but I want to disable it then when I'm actively prototyping and want to leave all warnings aside until I'm ready to refine the prototype

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For local Eslint, add a file to your project named `.eslintignore` and add any directories or files you want to ignore:

```
build/
src/
*.js
```

Though you might as well remove it entirely at this point.

---

This doesn't work with building or starting the code however, if you are using `create-react-app`. There is no way to disable Eslint without ejecting because it's built into react-scripts. Anytime any you build or start the server, it will run eslint using its internal configs aside from special cases defined in `package.json`. The only way around that is to eject or prepend each file with the disable comment as mentioned elsewhere. See [this issue on Github](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2339) for more information.

Comment: adding this file and content doesn't work. note I haven't run eject yet.

Comment: Ah, apparently that's on purpose: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2339

Only solution is to eject.

Comment: To clarify, there is no way to disable Eslint without ejecting because it's built into react-scripts. Anytime any you build or start the server, it will run eslint using its internal configs aside from special cases defined in `package.json`. The only way around that is to eject or prepend each file with the disable comment as mentioned elsewhere.

Answer (score 19):

Those warnings come from eslint. To disable them add [`/* eslint-disable */`](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments) at the top of the file you don't want to follow the eslint rules.

Comment: yes that works, but I don't want to do it for every file. how do I do it for everything. I don't want to see warnings at all.

Comment: I don't think it is currently possible https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2157 create-react-app is supposed to be opinionated in opposite to raw react.

Comment: I think it's possible if I npm run eject and then configure eslint on my own or something like this

Comment: @foreyez Oh yea you are definitely right about ejecting. It's up to you.

Answer (score 5):

For specific `eslint` warning supression insert the following code at the beginning of the file.

```
/* eslint-disable react/no-direct-mutation-state */
```

Answer (score 3):

Recently the ability to add your own editor configurations was added, this can be used to "partially" disable the functionality of ESLint. You just need to create a configuration file in the root directory.

`.eslintrc`:

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint"
}
```

`.env`

```
SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true
```

If you create a new application, it will *by default* come with a pre-filled `eslintConfig` object in the `package.json`

Comment: @SilvioBiasiol Yes, as long as you are using CRA 2.x.x+

Answer (score 3):

My rep is not high enough to comment on @fly's excellent answer, so I'll C+P it to add this instead:

For anyone looking for a temporary but quick and effective workaround for disabling console warnings from DevTools, this might do the trick.

Disclaimer - this might not work on versions that are not mine(react-scripts v3.0.1, react-dev-utils@^9.0.1), so use it at your own risk.

- enter this directory

`node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js`

- look for this function(should be around line 114)

`function handleWarnings(warnings) {`

- either add the `return` at the start of `function printWarnings()` (line 124), or comment out the call to `printWarnings()` in line 145.
- restart, eg with `npm run start`, for change to take effect.

This way, the hot reloader continues to work, but the annoying warnings *which have already been caught in my editor* are not output in the browser.

Answer (score 3):

To Completely Remove eslint warnings, what you can do is create a file named *.eslintignore* add * and save it. You wont see any more warning.

```
*
```

To Remove warnings from a particular folder means in the *.eslintignore* file add that folder name

```
/folder_name
/folder_name/file_name.js
```

You can also do this in the file level also. Add the following in the beginning of the file

```
/* eslint-disable */
```

To ignore the next line warning in a file

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to disable warnings in DevTools

1. Open the Console Tab.
2. Default levels/Custom levels -> uncheck Warnings

[image]

Comment: This will only hide warning from chrome

Comment: Yes that's why I specified "in DevTools"

Answer (score 3):

Set the `DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN` environment variable:

```sh
DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true npm start
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using create-react-app, then you can go into the package.json and edit the `eslintConfig` value. I just wanted to disable the "eqeqeq" and "no-unused-vars" rules, so mine looks like this:

```
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "eqeqeq": "off",
      "no-unused-vars": "off"
    }
  },
```

You'll have to re-run `npm start` for it to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for a temporary but quick and effective workaround for disabling console warnings from DevTools,
this might do the trick.

Disclaimer - this might not work on versions that are not mine(react-scripts v3.0.1, react-dev-utils@^9.0.1),
so use it at your own risk.

1. enter this directory

   node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js
2. look for this function(should be around line 114)

   function handleWarnings(warnings) {

and add a return statement right after it.

Your code should end up looking like this(if you're using webstorm)
[image: bye warnings]

That should shut the webpackHotDevClient.js:{whateverLineIdontCare} right up.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

**Add** a `.eslintignore` file and add

```
src/*
```

You can read more about this at

1. https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/ignoring-code
2. https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/rules

Answer (score 0):

You can use [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco) and configure craco.config.js for example

```
 module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: (webpackConfig) => {
      const ignoreWarnings = [{ module: /some module/, message: /some message/ }]
      return { ...webpackConfig, ignoreWarnings }
    }
  }
}
```

[more details here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/other-options/#ignorewarnings)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the typescript and/or linting errors with setting the environment variables in .env

TSC_COMPILE_ON_ERROR,
ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS, to true

more information on advanced configuration for create react app on

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/