# How to integrate javascript libraries into react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, techan.js

I have two javascript libraries that I need to integrate into my React app.  First I tried this:

```
import d3 from "https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"
import techan from "http://techanjs.org/techan.min.js"
```

That produced error:

> ./src/components/CandlestickChart/CandlestickChart.jsx Module not
> found: Can't resolve 'http://techanjs.org/techan.min.js' in
> 'C:\Users\Greg\Projects\react-demos\my-react-splitter-layout\src\components\CandlestickChart'

So I went to http://teckanjs.org/techan.min.js, copied the code, ran it through a beautifier, and saved it to techan.js, located in the same folder as CandlestickChart.jsx.  I changed import to

```
import techan from "./techan.js"
```

Then I got similar error:

> ./src/components/CandlestickChart/CandlestickChart.jsx Module not
> found: Can't resolve 'http://techanjs.org/techan.min.js' in
> 'C:\Users\Greg\Projects\react-demos\my-react-splitter-layout\src\components\CandlestickChart'

So I did the same thing as with the other one and changed the import to:

```
import d3 from "./d3.v4.js"
```

Then I got error:

> ./src/components/CandlestickChart/d3.v4.js Module not found: Can't
> resolve './requirejs' in
> 'C:\Users\Greg\Projects\react-demos\my-react-splitter-layout\src\components\CandlestickChart'

So I found requirejs online and did the same thing as the others and added an import to d3.v4.js like this:

```
import requirejs from "./requirejs";
```

But still getting the same error.  What's the trick to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install it as a local package. Run the following:

```
npm install d3
```

Then you'll be able to import it in your JavaScript:

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
```

Note the `"d3"`, not the `"./d3"` - the lack of the `./` indicates that you want to install from a module package, not from a file in the same directory.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the distinction. I took your advice and that seems to have eliminated the d3 errors.  But now I'm seeing this error: "Line 3:123:      'define' is not defined                                                no-undef
  Line 66:47:      Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions".  Lines 2-4 show: (function (t, n) {
    "object" == typeof exports && "undefined" != typeof module ? n(exports) : "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(["exports"], n) : n(t.d3 = t.d3 || {})
})(this, function (t) {

Comment: That is in src\components\CandlestickChart\techan.js

Comment: That's a linter warning, not a JavaScript error. But that's the minified version, and it's not *your* source code anyway, it's the library code, which there shouldn't be any need to modify.

Comment: Did you copy pieces of d3's source code into your own src folder? If so, don't do that - instead, *import* d3 with `import * as d3 from "d3"` only.

Comment: I had done that but now I've deleted it and did it your way.  The last error I reported causes "Failed to compile" so it seems to be more than just a warning.  This gets to a broader question of how to import 3rd party javascript libraries that don't have a convenient npm install available.

Comment: You can keep linter warnings from breaking the build process with a few approaches: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64518226 https://stackoverflow.com/q/48714225 But it's a bit ugly. Good thing the vast majority of libraries are installable via NPM nowadays.

Comment: You were right again.  I tried "npm install techan" and to my surprise it seemed to work. I changed the code like you showed me and now I'm getting a different error.  "TypeError: Cannot read property 'min' of undefined > 1422 | heikinashi: require('./heikinashi')(indicatorMixin, accessor.ohlc, d3.min, d3.max),".  But that appears to be a version issue or something in the library itself.  I'll accept your answer and try to figure that one out.  Thanks a lot!